# Como imprimir duas imagens em duas páginas diferentes de uma vez?

Tags: c#, panel, impressora

Olá!

Consigo imprimir um panel (pnlPrint) através do código a seguir. Mas, não estou conseguindo imprimir um datagridview que já pertence ao mesmo Form junto, na seguda página para que os dois saiam na mesma impressão.  Eu poderia fazer dois botões diferentes para imprimir os dois panels separados, mas preciso que os dois panels saiam na mesma impressão pois o usuário pode optar pela impressora PDF e assim gerar um arquivo de duas páginas.

```
   void Imprimir()
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.DocumentName = "Relatório SisIndice";
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog1.Document = pd;
        DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pd.Print();
        }
    }

    private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height, pnlPrint.CreateGraphics());
        pnlPrint.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height));
        RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
        float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left, bounds.Top, 1118, 855);


    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(dgvDetGraf.Width, dgvDetGraf.Height, dgvDetGraf.CreateGraphics());
        dgvDetGraf.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, dgvDetGraf.Width, dgvDetGraf.Height));
        RectangleF bounds1 = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, bounds1.Left, bounds1.Top, 1118, 855);

        e.HasMorePages = false;

    }
```

Comment: Um aparece sobreposto ao outro. 

Como faço para que o datagrid seja inserido em uma nova página?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver graças à ajuda de um integrante do stack (versão em inglês):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888445/how-to-print-two-bmp-into-two-different-pages/37890164#37890164

Comment: Seria interessante então você reproduzir a resposta aqui, ao inves de deixar apenas link. Fica mais fácil ver a solução e torna sua resposta aqui independente da resposta de la.